How is classical theism translated into mereology?
By classical theism, I mean the traditional scholastic Christian theism of figures like Thomas Aquinas, John Duns Scotus, Peter Abelard, Francisco Suárez, etc.
In contrast to panentheism (where creation is part of God, but God is a whole greater than creation), classical theism posits that creation and creator are two entirely separate wholes, with no overlapping or intersecting elements.
Evidently, the relationship between them needs to be explained, and this is done through analogia entis (analogy of being), which frames this relationship in proportional terms of a similarity between the two wholes, as well as an even greater dissimilarity, whereby the created whole depends entirely and absolutely on the creating whole while maintaining its relative autonomy as an independent whole.
At this point, I find myself rationally lost and unable to follow the argument. If there is a shared analogical relationship between these two independent wholes, that would imply the existence of a whole as a "common ratio" greater than God (!) that encompasses both independent wholes. This would turn the dualism into a monism—not only logically but also ontologically, since in some way God must intervene in the created whole.
If anyone can explain how this can be understood mereologically without falling into inconsistencies, I would be very grateful.

@MauroALLEGRANZA How can it be clear if that is precisely my question?
Regarding the Trinity: it is already a revealed thesis and does not have to be argued ‘from’ a natural perspective. But theism does not.

Your third section about analogia entis starting "Evidently, the relationship ..." is rather unclear. Please choose one theologian from "traditional scholastic Christian theism" together with a precise quote of his argumentation and a reference from his work. - Are you sure that scholastic theologians operated on the basis of an elaborated mereology?

Per classical theism, God and creation do not belong to a common genus, which otherwise would indeed suggest a 'higher whole' encompassing both. Instead, God is seen as the source of all being as the act of existence itself, while creatures are participants in being. This participation is not mereological in the sense of shared parts, but rather a metaphysical dependency where the very being of creatures is 'borrowed' from God’s act of creation which is required to be 'redeemed'. God is not a being among beings but rather Being itself. Even in analogy the dissimilarity is always greater...

@DoubleKnot Thus, not all metaphysical situations are translatable mereologically?

Indeed, at most metaphorically at least for Aquina's analogia entis thesis but not mereologically literally...


that would imply the existence of a whole as a "common ratio" greater than God (!) that encompasses both independent wholes.

I suspect that forming the "common ratio" implicitly takes a very strong stand on the extensionality and composability of objects. While it's definitely natural to say something like "God and all His creation", I think a defender of the analogy-of-being argument could take issue with the idea that that composite object "actually exists"
The best non-theism analogy I can come up with is: If I have a chair and a table, I can talk about the 'chair-table combination', and if I have  a chair and my friend Kevin, I can talk about the 'chair-Kevin combination'. For each of those composite objects, I can talk about their mass, their shape, etc.
If I have a 4-legged chair and 'the number 4', there is an evident relation between the two. The chair, perhaps, represents or embodies or inherits something from 'the number 4'! But it's not obvious what mereological whole would be formed from the sum of those two parts. What does "4 and this chair" weigh? How does one do math with "4 and this chair"? It's not clear that there's any properties that we can assign to "4 and this chair", other than that it is composed of those parts. If we can't say anything about it, does it make sense to say the composite exists?
If one is willing to deny the composite "4 and this chair" its existence, I think (by analogy) one can certainly reject the existence of "God and this chair", preserving both God's supremacy and non-intersection with creation.

Analogia entis is, I think it's fair to say, a bit of a get-out-of-jail free card with regards to logic. Because the "God is" and "creation *is" are entirely different and related only by analogy, one can usually wriggle out of contradictions. (Saving us from awkwardness like "The children of sheep are also sheep. God is a lamb. God is our father. Therefore I am a sheep.")
